# Can't add custom field from registration form in AngularJS + Stormpath

Tags: stormpath

I want to add a custom field during new user registration but it shows an error message:

> is not a configured registration field.

But documentation on page https://docs.stormpath.com/angularjs/sdk/#/api/stormpath.spRegistrationForm:spRegistrationForm states:

> Any form fields you supply that are not one of the default fields (first name, last name) will be automatically placed into the new account's customa data object.

The code I use:

```html
<form ng-submit="submit()">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="formModel.givenName" required="" ng-disabled="creating">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="formModel.surname" required="" ng-disabled="creating">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="formModel.email" required="" ng-disabled="creating">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="formModel.password" required="" ng-disabled="creating">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Custom field" ng-model="formModel.customfield" required="" ng-disabled="creating">
 </div>
  
 <p class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="error>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="creating">Register</button>
</form>
```

How can I add custom field on registration form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message it sounds like you are using our Express-Stormpath library on your backend (please let me know if this is not correct).

You will need to configure your fields in the Express server as well.  We require sever-side form configuration as well, to prevent arbitrary requests to the user's custom data object.

Documentation on the form configuration can be found here:

http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/registration.html#creating-custom-fields

Hope this helps!  P.S. I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to submit a more up-to-date answer for anybody out there now with this problem. After digging through `node_modules/express-stormpath/lib/helpers/get-required-registration-fields.j` I noticed on line 26 that the code references `config.web.register.fields` while the documentation references web.register.form.fields. By removing the `form` key and promoting the fields key up one everything worked!

Comment: btw, I'm on: `"express-stormpath": "^2.4.0"`

Comment: Server side should be like this

======
web: {
    produces: ['application/json'],
    register: {
      enabled: true,
      uri: '',
      form: {
        fields: {
          organization_id: {
            enabled: true,
            required: true,
          }
        }
      }
    }
======

Answer (score 0):

## In Server side the stormpath init should be like this

```
web: { 
produces: 
['application/json'],
 register: {
 enabled: true, 
 uri: '', 
form: {
 fields: 
{ organization_id: { enabled: true, required: true, } }
 } 
}
```

======